# What does the DNA symbol mean in Corvo Bianco?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I just moved into Corvo Bianco and applied all possible upgrades. There are a few symbols in minimap.

Bed, bookshelf, chemistry lab, bombs and potions, and a DNA. I believe DNA is something about signs, but I could neither find nor was able to use it. What is that symbol, and where shall I find it?

[image]

Comment: Mutagens, I think. Witchers are mutants, after all.

Comment: @RavenDreamer * [mutates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutate_(comics)), please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice the two small red triangles pointing down from the two lower icons.  These locations are *below* where you're currently standing.

In the Alchemy Lab in the Wine Cellar below Corvo Bianco are two tables.

The Eastern one (center of the room), about which you ask, allows you to turn species specific mutagens into generic mutagens.  You can finally turn all of those pointless werewolf mutagens into far more useful (lesser) red mutagens! This is most valuable for purchasing Mutation upgrades in your Character screen.

The Western table (in the alcove) allows you to recharge your potions & grenades w/o spending time meditating.  Given that the bed upstairs also gives you such nice buffs for spending only one hour, I don't make much use of it.

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the contraptions in the alchemy lab. In addition to the table is something that permits you to transmute mutagens - IIRC, transmuting monster-specific mutagens into the generic red, green, or blue variety. (Which is useful if you're trying to upgrade your advanced mutagen talents.)